# Get value of binded HTML dropdownlist with sql in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

### Details of my Problem.

I am using the html inputs in Asp.Net Web Forms to bind the drop-down list with the column values of a table in SQL DB. **I am able to do that**.

The problem is when I select the value at run time and store it in the Table it stores 0 as the value in that column of table.

## Code

Here is the Code of aspx.cs and I am calling this on Page Load Event

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select Member_ID from ColonyResidentialEmp", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda =new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    sda.Fill(ds);

    if (ds!= null)
    {
        FamMemID.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        FamMemID.DataTextField = "Member_ID";
        FamMemID.DataValueField = "Member_ID";
        FamMemID.DataBind();
        FamMemID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Member ID", "0"));
    }

}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(sqlEx.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Here I am trying to set the value of selected Option from drop-down list but getting 0 in result.

```
FamMemObj._MemID = FamMemID.Value;
```

This is the simple html control to select the value, by default there is no value. Value will be display only on page load after getting data from table.

```
<div class="controls">
    <select class="form-control" id="FamMemID" name="FamMemID" runat="server" >
        <option value="">Select Member ID</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here I'm posting some screen shots for the ease.

[Front End of My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wPrw.png)

[What i am getting in Table Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1vZx.png)

Waiting for Precise and Perfect Answer. Please Correct Me where I am doing wrong Thanks in advance :)

P.S: I just want to use HTML Tags not asp.

Comment: Did you wrap your data binding code in `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`? If not, you are rebinding the drop down every time, thus loosing the selected value

Comment: `catch (SqlException sqlEx){throw new ApplicationException(sqlEx.Message);}` please please please don't do this.

Comment: @Andrei such a small mistake by me. Yeah Thanks it worked. Wondering how can i forget this. Rep++. Thanks Mate.

Comment: @asawyer why? What's the issue?

Comment: Your taking the exception showing you the full stack trace, error codes, data, inner exception, ect and throwing it all down the drain. The new exception will list this catch as the stack trace, you'll have no proper debug information and everyone down the list maintaning this (ex: you in 6 months) will hate you with a burning passion for it and will have to waste their time going through and removing all the unneeded try/catch blocks that follow this awful anti-pattern.